# How to hide grid line protrusion in bar chart

Tags: highcharts

I'm using Highcharts, and want to hide the protrusion of grid line out of the graph area. I mean,

it looks like this now:
[image]

and I want it to look like this (The protrusion of grid line in the right of the chart is hidden):

[image]

The highcharts config is below:

```
{
  chart: {
    width: 420,
    height: 350,
    style: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      'text-align': 'center',
    },
  },
  colors: ['#a1cbff'],
  title: {
    text: undefined,
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: { text: undefined },
    tickInterval: 0.1,
    max: 1,
    min: 0,
    gridLineWidth: 1,
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: { text: undefined },
  }],
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    pointPlacement: 'between',
    data: [...SOME_DATA],
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      groupPadding: 0,
      shadow: false,
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter() { return this.y; },
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  exporting: false,
  credits: false,
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, however, it is not so simple and intuitive to make it as you expect in Highcharts. Check the demo and code posted below, there you will find the solution with `pointRange = 0.1`, `pointPlacement = -0.5`, `min: 0.05`, `max: 0.95` and `tickInterval = 0.1`.

**Code:**

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    width: 420,
    height: 350,
    style: {
      textAlign: 'center',
      'text-align': 'center',
    },
  },
  colors: ['#a1cbff'],
  title: {
    text: undefined,
  },
  yAxis: [{
    title: {
      text: undefined
    }
  }],
  xAxis: {
    min: 0.05,
    max: 0.95,
    tickInterval: 0.1
  },
  series: [{
    type: 'column',
    pointPlacement: -0.5,
    pointRange: 0.1,
    data: [
      [0.1, 130],
      [0.2, 110],
      [0.3, 240],
      [0.4, 150],
      [0.5, 250],
      [0.6, 190],
      [0.7, 240],
      [0.8, 220],
      [0.9, 270],
      [1, 160]
    ],
  }],
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      pointPadding: 0,
      borderWidth: 1,
      groupPadding: 0,
      shadow: false,
    },
  },
  tooltip: {
    formatter() {
      return this.y;
    },
  },
  legend: {
    enabled: false,
  },
  exporting: false,
  credits: false,
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/wtxd9y2f/

**API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointRange 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.pointPlacement

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!